# 179 page book TOC stops at page 129. The whole volume compiles

Tags: table-of-contents, books

I have a book of poems with 179 pages but my  TOC stops at page 129. There  9 chapters but the TOC stops partway though ch 7. There are often 2 or 3 poems to a page. The whole volume compiles.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are no limits to the size of a ToC, so I guess something changes in your document and makes it stop. Look at the part of the book where the ToC stops and see if there is some suspect command. If you don't find anything, then show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You might also want to review the `.toc` file. It is also unclear if you are getting any error or warning messages.